# Getting nothing when doing cross domain AJAX request with YQL

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cross-domain, yql

I am using the following code to do the **cross domain AJAX request with YQL** :

```
function requestCrossDomain( site, callback ) {

function cbFunc(data) {
// If we have something to work with...
alert("inside call back");
if ( data.results[0] ) {
    // Strip out all script tags, for security reasons.
    // BE VERY CAREFUL. This helps, but we should do more. 
    data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');

    // If the user passed a callback, and it
    // is a function, call it, and send through the data var.
    if ( typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(data);
    }
}
// Else, Maybe we requested a site that doesn't exist, and nothing returned.
else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
}   
// If no url was passed, exit.
if ( !site ) {
    alert('No site was passed.');
    return false;
}

// Take the provided url, and add it to a YQL query. Make sure you encode it!
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=cbFunc';

// Request that YSQL string, and run a callback function.
// Pass a defined function to prevent cache-busting.
$.getJSON( yql, cbFunc );
console.log("outside call back");

}
```

and calling the above as follow :
    `requestCrossDomain('http://www.cnn.com', function(results) {

       alert(results);

    });`

When i am running the above code in firefox, although response (in firebug console) is showing the content of website inside callback function (cbFunc) yet it is showing nothing as alert.
Also the result of `console.log("inside call back")` at line 5 is not printing in firebug console.
**can anyone suggest me where things are going wrong or any explanation for above ?** 
btw i have already gone through :
http://tek-insight.blogspot.in/2010/05/cross-domain-ajax-request-proxy-json.html
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/
Possible explanation in related stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) accepts as callback function for 'success' response. But if error were returned (404, 500, etc) then it will not call this function.
You need to add extra functions in order to catch other scenarios of responses:

```
$.getJSON( yql, cbFunc)
  .done(function() { console.log( "second success" ); })
  .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) { console.log( "error", textStatus, error ); })
  .always(function() { console.log( "complete" ); });
```

Comment: it is showing "error" and "complete" in console. can you explain why ?

Comment: It means that response did not returned success header with 200 code, but did returned something else. I've modified answer above that now contain additional fields in callback that you can inspect.

Comment: It means that data from response is not valid JSON.
Using chrome open Dev Tools, then navigate to "Network" tab, then execute your AJAX request, and find the request in list below. Select it and go to "Response" section - probably will not be valid JSON, or even something else totally.

Use Dev Tools in order to validate this stuff.

Comment: In response tab there is cbFunc() which contains all the requested data in "json" format. Using firebug its showing "json parse error". so does it means that result is depend upon the data send by the server (i.e. json error is due to wrong json by server) or any thing else.please clearify this...

Comment: It means that server sends invalid JSON data or possibly not JSON at all. In chrome Dev Tools there is Network tab, please see there response from server and if it is JSON, validate it using this service: http://jsonlint.com/ it will show you an error in JSON.